# Funcionalidade de caixa de texto de Cmd para Git

Tags: git, windows, cmd, batch

Estou desenvolvendo um `.bat`, que fará uma série de comandos do `git` pré-definidos. Mas um desses comandos, é necessário que o usuário digite uma mensagem de operação.

Segue a série de comandos:

```
cd C:\xampp\htdocs\laravelapi
set filedatetime=%date% // ou qualquer outra data
set filedatetime=%filedatetime:~0,2%%filedatetime:~3,2%%filedatetime:~6,4%
git add .
git commit -m "Novo versionamento %filedatetime%%username%"
git push
```

Há de alguma forma fazer com que ao executar o `.bat`, ele abra uma caixa de texto na tela para o usuário digitar a mensagem e assim guardar em uma variável antes do `git commit -m "Novo versionamento %filedatetime%%username%"`?

Estou usando Windows 10 Home.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Você pode usar o `set /p` para solicitar a entrada de informação e associar à uma variável.

A sintaxe é: `set /p nome_da_variavel="Texto de solicitação: "`

No seu código, seria o equivalente à:

```
@echo off

cd C:\xampp\htdocs\laravelapi
REM defina a data abaixo
set filedatetime=%date%
set filedatetime=%filedatetime:~0,2%%filedatetime:~3,2%%filedatetime:~6,4%

set /p message="Digite o comentário do commit: "

git add .
git commit -m "%message% %filedatetime%%username%"
git push
```

Comment: vlw cara, ajudou mesmo!

Answer (score 5):

O formato/layout/strings da data na variável **`%date%`** muda conforme: região, idioma e/ou configurações feitas pelo usuário:

---

A variável **`%date%`** vai sempre exibir a data no formato segundo idioma & país, ou num formato customizado/configurado pelo usuário, ou seja, não segue layout/padrão fixo, onde podemos trabalhar de forma preditiva, e, consequentemente, manipular a string de saída, contando com um layout fixo/previsível

Sugiro usar o **`wmic.exe`**, onde, seguramente, tens uma saída padronizada e independente de qualquer região, idioma e/ou qualquer configurações feitas pelo usuário.

Usando o **`wmic.exe`** para obter a data num layout/formato confiável, onde as configurações do usuário, de idioma ou de região não sofrem qualquer alteração...

Referências:

- **[Safe way to get current day month and year in batch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12635541/safe-way-to-get-current-day-month-and-year-in-batch)**
- **[Parsing dates in batch files regional settings locale](https://helgeklein.com/blog/2011/02/parsing-dates-in-batch-files-regional-settings-locale/)**

> - Alternativa para compor o layout de data pegando mês/dia com zero quando menor/igual 9:

---

```
set "filedatetime=!_day!-!_Month!-!_year!"
set "filedatetime=!_Month!/!_day!/!_year!"
set "filedatetime=!_year!-!_Month!-!_day!"
set "filedatetime=!_day!!_Month!!_year!"
set "filedatetime=!_Month!!_day!!_year!"
set "filedatetime=!_year!!_Month!!_day!"
```

---

- Exemplo usando zero para **`mês/dia >=9`** e também o pegando/setando as variáveis **`Year, Month`** e **`Day`** separadamente para montar o layout de data desejado:

```
wmic.exe Path Win32_LocalTime Get Year,Month,Day
```

---

Portando para o **[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)/[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)**:

---

```
@echo off && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

@%__APPDIR__%mode.com con:cols=60 lines=8
title <nul & title Add Send Versionamento

for %%i in (Year,Month,Day)do for /f %%I in ('
%__APPDIR__%wbem\wmic.exe Path Win32_LocalTime Get "%%~i"^|%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe [0-9]
')do if not "%%~i"=="Year" (set "_%%~i=0%%~I" && call set "_%%~i=!_%%~i:~-2!") else set "_%%~i=%%~I"

rem :: Obs.: Invertendo a data e usando zero: ano/ 0+mês/ 0+dia,  ::
rem :: Vai obter um mesmo número de dígitos e sempre crescente. ::
set "filedatetime=!_year!!_Month!!_day!" 

cd /d "C:\xampp\htdocs\laravelapi"

:loop
echo/ & set /p "_message="Digite Mensagem: "
echo/!_message!|%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe [a-Z] >nul || cls && goto :loop

cmd.exe /v /c git add .
cmd.exe /v /c git commit -m "!_message! Ref: !filedatetime!/%username%"
cmd.exe /v /c git push

%__APPDIR__%timeout.exe -1 & endlocal && goto :EOF
```

---

- Para o input: **`Versão de !date!`**
- Comando: **`git commit -m "!_message! Ref: !filedatetime!/%username%"`**, Resulta:

```
"Versão de 2020-02-19 Ref: 20200219/ecker"
```

---

**Obs.:**

**`set /p`** não lhe retorna qualquer indicativo informando que o usuário digitou um conjunto de caracteres,ou o <kbd>Enter</kbd> apenas, onde, alguns comando adicionais são podem serem usados para verificar se o **input** (variável: **`!_message!`** ) recebeu efetivamente valor/caracteres....

- Pegando a data num formato preditivo, em layout previsível e confiável
- Obtém o inputs em looping, que vai verifica a presença ou não de caracteres
- Previne a execução dos próximos comandos quando input é nulo/sem caracteres
- Ficar em looping se o usuário não digitar nada e/ou apenas pressionar ENTER

  ---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

```
@echo off && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

@%__APPDIR__%mode.com con:cols=60 lines=8
title <nul & title Add Send Versionamento

cd /d "C:\xampp\htdocs\laravelapi"
for /f "tokens=2delims==." %%i in (
'%__APPDIR__%\wbem\wmic.exe OS Get localdatetime /value^|findstr [0-9]'
) do set "_d=%%i" && call set "filedatetime=!_d:~6,2!!_d:~4,2!!_d:~0,4!

echo/ Data Layout : !_d:~6,2!/!_d:~4,2!/!_d:~0,4!- !_d:~8,2!:!_d:~10,2!]

:loop
echo/ & set /p "_message="Digite Mensagem: "
echo/!_message!|%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe [a-Z] >nul || cls && goto :loop

cmd.exe /v /c git add .
cmd.exe /v /c git commit -m "!_message! Ref: !filedatetime!/%username%"
cmd.exe /v /c git push

%__APPDIR__%timeout.exe -1 & endlocal & goto :EOF
```

---

- Ou com um input box hibrido com VBS:


  ---

```
<!-- ::  
@%__APPDIR__%mode.com con:cols=60 lines=8
@echo off && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

title <nul & title Add Send Versionamento

cd /d "C:\xampp\htdocs\laravelapi"
for /f "tokens=2delims==." %%i in (
'%__APPDIR__%\wbem\wmic.exe OS Get localdatetime /value^|findstr [0-9]'
) do set "_d=%%i" && call set "filedatetime=!_d:~6,2!!_d:~4,2!!_d:~0,4!

echo/ Data Layout : !_d:~6,2!/!_d:~4,2!/!_d:~0,4!- !_d:~8,2!:!_d:~10,2!

:loop
for /f "tokens=*delims= " %%i in ('%__APPDIR__%CScript.exe //NoLogo "%~f0?.wsf"')do set "_message=%%~i"
echo/!_message!|%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe [a-Z] >nul || goto :loop

cmd.exe /v /c git add .
cmd.exe /v /c git commit -m "!_message! Ref: !filedatetime!/%username%"
cmd.exe /v /c git push

%__APPDIR__%timeout.exe -1 & endlocal & goto :EOF
# --><job><script language="vbscript">
Input=InputBox("Digite Mensagem: ", "Novo Versionamento: "): wsh.echo Input: Set Input=Nothing
</script></job>
```

---

- Input/output:

  ---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não, a minha resposta não funciona para outros formatos de data ou cultura, e também não é necessário fazer isso. Respondi o que o autor perguntou, e não enfentei a resposta com coisas que seriam desnecessárias para ele. Parece que será para uso pessoal e portanto não irá ter alteração de cultura/data constantes, sempre esperará algo do sistema. E se ele quiser fazer algo mais abrangente, outra pergunta mais específica seria feita. Uma pergunta simples pode receber uma resposta simples.

Comment: Se não entendi, explique. O que entendi é que você quer que eu torne minha resposta ampla o suficiente para ser poluída a ponto de nem responder a pergunta do autor colocando conteúdo desnecessário. E sobre "apoio", se isso for voto para você, sugiro que esteja utilizando de forma errônea o site. Votos não devem ser pessoais ou intrapessoais, e sim conforme o conteúdo.